# EF Core, How to update a record in table which has both One To Many and Many to Many relationships with the same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MainCourseId { get; set; }
    public Course MainCourse { get; set; }
    public IList<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class StudentCourse
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

There are two issues.
First issue is, the above migration is not creating the MainCourseId , gives this error.
"Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Students_Courses_MainCourseId' on table 'Students' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors."

Second is, in another system where structure of entities are same, updating an existing record with a modifed value in MainCourseId doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your db structure has a bug. You need to add List of StudentCourse to Course class too. IMHO it is not the best db structure I have seen.  Much  better way is to add Id to  StudentCourse table and a flag if it is a main course.

```
public class StudentCourse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public bool IsMainCourse {get; set;}
}
```

and since you are using net5  you can add another lists to the classes

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual List<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Student> Students{ get; set; }
    public virtual List<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}
```

you need to make a new init migration to use this structure

Comment: *"Your db structure has a bug. You need to add List of StudentCourse to Course class too"* No, you don't. Collection navigation property is not mandatory. The problem is completely different. The suggested design with flag is good though :-)

Comment: Yes.  Using a flag is good because it requires the MainCourse to be one of the Student's Courses, and you can set a unique constraint on (StudentId,IsMainCourse) to enforce that a student has at most one MainCourse.

Comment: This is highlighting that there is a property of THE RELATIONSHIP, not either of the Entities.  Is is the "maincourse" for (all courses)? No.   It is the main course for the student-and-course-combination, then the "extra" goes on the Joining Entity.    Now, the location of the IsMainCourse is correct.     In general I thing "bool" flags are almost always short sighted.    a public short StudentCourseStatus    ... and the values could be UNKNOWN(0), Main(1), Secondary(2)          but you have a future proofing for others.  bool flags almost always let you down....in the long haul.

Comment: other possible names for StudentCourse could be "StudentCourseLink" or "StudentToCourse", etc, etc #namesAreHard      but the idea is correct.     there are simple M:N, and there are properties on the RELATIONSHIP M:N's .. I've learned the hardway to go ahead and code the StudentCourse(Link) object .. at the start......because somebody will come along and ask for a property on the relationship .. but I'm upvoting this suggestion/answer.

Comment: Oh yeah, if you ever need to FK ~from StudentCourse(Link), then having a dedicated  StudentCourse(Link) (table) with a PK of StudentCourseLinkKey as PK...makes that future doable as well.  PS I use "Key" instead of "Id" as Id can be ambiguous.

Comment: @IvanStoev I am agree with you. But it is much better to have this. Do you remember several days ago we disscussed with you the case where we couldn't make a right query because a many-to-many relation table was in a shadow.

Comment: @granadaCoder I am agree with you.  For me,   public int MainCourseId { get; set; } property looks as  a fifth wheel for the car. it is only interfering.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have cascade delete that creates a multiple cascade paths.  Here deleting a Course would delete both all the StudentCourses for that Course and all the Students that have that as their MainCourse.

But EF won't configure CascadeDelete if your MainCourse is optional, as it probably should be to enable you to store a Student that has no MainCourse.  So to fix both issues, just make Student.MainCourseId optional by changing the type to `int?`.:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? MainCourseId { get; set; }
    public Course MainCourse { get; set; }
    public IList<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can leave it as required and configure the relationship not to cascade deletes.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .HasOne(s => s.MainCourse)
                .WithMany()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    modelBuilder.Entity<StudentCourse>()
                .HasKey(e => new { e.StudentId, e.CourseId });

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I think it might be more convenient to use "skip navigation properties" so Student has Courses, and a Course has Students, which you can do in EF Core 5+ with Many-to-Many mapping, like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EfCore6Test
{ 


     public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? MainCourseId { get; set; }
        public Course MainCourse { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; } = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Student> Students { get; } = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public class StudentCourse
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public Student Student { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public Course Course { get; set; }
    }

    public class Db: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasOne(s => s.MainCourse).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasMany(s => s.Courses).WithMany(c => c.Students).UsingEntity<StudentCourse>(
                sc => sc.HasOne(e => e.Course).WithMany(),
                sc => sc.HasOne(e => e.Student).WithMany()
                ); 

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;database=efCore6Test;Integrated Security=true;TrustServerCertificate=true", o => o.UseRelationalNulls(true))
                .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information);
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                
                using var db = new Db();
                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();
                var joe = new Student() {Name="Joe" };
                var math = new Course() { CourseName = "Math" };
                var english = new Course() { CourseName = "English" };


                joe.Courses.Add(math);
                joe.Courses.Add(english);

                joe.MainCourse = english; 

                db.Students.Add(joe);

                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            {

                using var db = new Db();
                var joe = db.Students.Where(s => s.Name == "Joe").First();
                var math = db.Courses.Where(c => c.CourseName == "Math").First();
                joe.MainCourse = math;

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"You should use the Many-to-Many functionality in EF Core 5"* Why? Using "old style" many-to-many with explicit join entity is perfectly fine in v5 and any future version. And how this relates to the original problem? The problem is not even in many-to-many (one or another way), but the additional many-to-one represented by the required `Student.MainCourseId` FK and should be solved there.

Comment: M2M simplifies the consuming code because you don't have to mess with StudentCourse entities for most scenarios.  And I flipped the Student>MainCourse to be optional because it's probably possible to have a student with no courses, but having it required doesn't break anything.

Comment: Yes, making it optional is ok. But many-to-many suggestion is just opinionated, thus you should simply remove it. Both approaches have pros and cons, and neither can be favored for all scenarios. And what exactly is "most", any prove? Implicit is easier for reading, but adding/removing links is much harder, if not possible at all w/o loading "other side" entities you don't really need.

Comment: There isn't an example in the doc of using a mapping entity that appears in the model, but isn't used in any Navigation Properties.  I think that's a useful application of M2M.  Yes it's opinionated, but just like initializing the collection nav properties with `HashSet<T>` it's just a suggestion for improving while fixing the error.  Otherwise this question is just another dup of the `may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths` question.

Comment: What's wrong with that if the question actually *is* another dup of the aforementioned issue? And should be closed as such rather that answered. All these opinionated statements and redundant bunch of code just hide (I didn't notice it until you mentioned in the response to my first comment) the actual fix. Because just making the FK nullable makes the relationship optional, thus no cascade delete, thus no multiple cascade paths, thus no further action needed. I doubt any future reader (including OP) will notice that either.

Comment: I did not know that optional FK's aren't configured with cascade delete by default.  I'll update the answer to highlight the fix, and clarify that the "improved" model is just a suggestion.